# Operator new implementation visibility issue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

It's said that, as a good practice, when implementing one of the forms of the operator `new` for a class, it is recommended that all the others forms also must be implemented. If don't, due to `c++` not intuitive visibility rules, bad things can happen. What are these bad things and how do they happen? Can the not implemented forms get hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about overloading the global operator `new` function versus a class-specific `operator new`.

TL;DR: If you want to have fine-grained memory control, you may wish to consider using an Allocator paradigm, like the standard containers. The rules are complicated and error-prone.

The most common reason to implement all of them is due to the confusing calling contexts. Often, the class-specific new will be implemented in terms of the global operator. However, this is not required, so you can get surprised.

For example, let's say you wrote `class A` and `class B` and you want to control allocation. You write overrides for `A` and `B`.

```
void *very_clever_allocator(size_t sz);

class A {
    void* operator new(size_t sz) {
        return very_clever_allocator(sz);
    }
};

class B {
    void* operator new(size_t sz) {
        return very_clever_allocator(sz);
    }
};
```

A well-intentioned user of your code writes:

```
void *operator(size_t sz) {
    return incompatible_allocator(sz);
}
```

If someone allocates your class with `::new A;` then the class-specific version is ignored. So all of a sudden, a different allocator is used. The programmer may not be careful, and calls delete. Since you are careful, you have also defined `operator delete`. But now, your `very_clever_allocator` doesn't know about this object. This will be a hard to diagnose bug.

This is not common, but since these rules are very complicated, it's usually easier to use an `Allocator`. If you're just writing code to debug, this is OK for a one time thing.

More reading:
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/17/the-many-faces-of-operator-new-in-c